# Google Earth Engine Authentication problems

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm using QGIS 3.22.0 (Bialowieza)

I'm trying to work with the GHSL-S2 plugin. As far as my research goes, it is important to install the plugin Google Earth Engine.
I have an active account with google Earth Engine and I'm following the instruction to import it into QGIS with [this technical report](https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/documents/GHSL_S2_plugin_User_Guide.pdf?rnd=0.6892737559974194). However, when I try to import Earth Engine in QGIS I always get the same error message. Meanwhile, ob the webpage I get the message that the authentification was a success.

```
import ee
Starting Google Earth Engine Authorization ...
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2022 15:51:01] "GET /?code=4/0AfgeXvtQoAm0vILGA3qm7sE41n7YcmvCBO_mMdNVcJ44vAuIvJySSQ5_63DC5OCDzcjrkA&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/earthengine%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Taani\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 221, in get_persistent_credentials
    return Credentials(None, **oauth.get_credentials_arguments())
  File "C:\Users\Taani\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\oauth.py", line 68, in get_credentials_arguments
    with open(get_credentials_path()) as creds:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Taani/.config/earthengine/credentials'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/Taani/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\__init__.py", line 42, in __wrapping_ee_import__
    _module_.Initialize(http_transport=httplib2.Http())
  File "C:\Users\Taani\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 127, in Initialize
    credentials = data.get_persistent_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\Taani\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 223, in get_persistent_credentials
    raise ee_exception.EEException(
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1415, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 919, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users/Taani/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\__init__.py", line 44, in __wrapping_ee_import__
    if authenticate(ee=_module_):
  File "C:\Users/Taani/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\ee_auth.py", line 84, in authenticate
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(ee.oauth.TOKEN_URI, data).read().decode()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I dont have much experience with python or command lines, I'm finding it hard to understand how I can get earth engine to work. I only need to to use GHSL.

I have installed Idle Shell in Order to authenticate GEE, however with no success. I'm having trouble finding online any kind of tutorial, and since I havent used Python much, I cannot deduce how to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you follow the error message suggestion? *`earthengine authenticate` in your command line, and then retry.*

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you have the python Earth Engine API installed.

In cmd type:
`earthengine`

If it's not installed, you will see a message saying:

*earthengine is not an internal or external command...*

To install the API type the following in cmd:

`pip install earthengine-api`

Then you can try to authenticate using Python

```py
import ee
# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()
# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()
```

This will open a website where you will be able to get the required code

Comment: I have tried that beforehand with the Idle Shell. However, this was not successfull. The first step is already not working.

Comment: It looks like you don't have earthengine installed. I will add to the answer the instructions to install it.